# OpenACC dependency error

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openacc

Please I need some help here:

```
    void RBM::sample_v_given_h(int *h0_sample, double *mean, int *sample) {

          int c = 0;
          double r;

      for(int i=0; i<n_visible; i++) {
        mean[i] = propdown(h0_sample, i, vbias[i]);


          if(mean[i] < 0 || mean[i] > 1) 
           sample[i] = 0;
          else{
          r = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
          if (r < mean[i]) c++;

        sample[i] = c;
        }
      }          
    }
```

when I use rand() to generate random number as previous example, the PGI compiler gives me an error:

```
  Procedures called in a compute region must have acc routine information: rand (./RBM.cpp: 166)
```

or as following

```
   Accelerator restriction: call to 'rand' with no acc routine
```

when I call function which has rand()

Comment: I think I should add  "#pragma acc routine" but how to add it since it runs outside in other library.

Comment: In general, rand() is not thread safe, so it's likely to give you troubles on the accelerator even if you were to decorate the declaration with `acc routine`. What I've done in the past it allocate an array for random numbers, then use cuRand to pre-generate a bunch of random numbers in parallel and then use those inside my code where I had been calling rand(). I've looked into making calls to device-side cuRand from OpenACC, but I've found that more difficult to do than it's worth.